# Hacer reporte mensual de datos sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Como puedo sacar datos mensuales por ejemplo de día 1 a 1 o en el caso de que esté en el mes actual del día 1 hasta el actual.

Teniendo una tabla tal que así:

```
+---------------------------------------+
|  id  |  estado   |         fecha      |
+------+-----------+--------------------+
|  1   |    10     | 2017-02-13 9:30:00 |
|  2   |    10     | 2017-02-13 9:30:00 |
|  3   |    10     | 2017-02-14 9:30:00 |
|  4   |    10     | 2017-02-15 9:30:00 |
|  5   |    10     | 2017-02-15 9:30:00 |
|  6   |    10     | 2017-02-15 9:30:00 |
|  7   |    10     | 2017-02-16 9:30:00 |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Quiero sacar por cada día cuantos estados de cada se cambian.
Por ejemplo el día 13 hay 2, el 14 hay 1, el 15 hay 3, el 16 hay 1, como puedo sacar esos datos, sobretodo importante que sea mensual de día 1 a día 1..

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecciona el `COUNT(estado)` y lo agrupas por el día usando la función `DAY`:

```
SELECT DAY(fecha), COUNT(estado) FROM Table_Name GROUP BY DAY(fecha);
```